# Regular Expresssion does not catch the last digit

Tags: python, regex

I have the following cases I want to capture:

```
| Task| Text | Capture | 
|:---- |:------| :-----|
| Capture| 1.304 /XXX 0.0000 XX 15/Oct/2000    | 1.304 and 0.000 |
| Capture | XXX 1.304% - XXXX 15.10.2044 XXX | 1.304 but not part of the date 15.10.2044|
| Capture| XXX 11,8275% XXX1 AAA    | 11,8275|
| Capture| XX 0.0. vs. 2.895    | 2.895 |
| Capture| XX 0.0. vs. 2.895.    | 2.895 |
```

I have created the following regular expression:

```
(?<![,\.])(\d+[,.]\d+)[^,\.]%*
```

with

```
re.findall(r'(?<![,\.])(\d+[,.]\d+)[^,\.]%*',text)
```

The problem is that it is not able to detect the last two cases with `2.895`. In one case it detects `2.89` and in the last case it is not able to detect because of the full stop. I want it detect the decimal at the end of the sentence even if the sentence ends with a full stop.

Comment: `[^,\.]` is matching the last digit, and it's not inside the capture group.

Comment: Aside: You don't have to escape `.` inside `[]`.

Comment: I think what you want is a negative lookahead, not a negated character set.

Comment: @Barmar I have now tried with a negative lookahead (`(?<![,\.])(\d+[,.]\d+)(?!:^,\.)%*`) which now works for the last two but it captures `15.10` in `XXX 1.304% - XXXX 15.10.2044 XXX` which I want to prevent.

Comment: @anubhava `(?<![,.])(\d+[,.]\d+)\b` this also captures `15.10` in `XXX 1.304% - XXXX 15.10.2044 XXX` which it shouldn't.

Comment: The negative lookahead should be: `$(?![,.])`

Comment: @anubhava this is much better but fails for the last case where I have a full stop at the end of the sentence right after the decimal number.

Comment: @Barmar `(?<![,\.])(\d+[,.]\d+)$(?![,.])` does not work. It is not able to catch almost anything. Fails for case 1,2,3,5.

Comment: @anubhava The last case where you have a full stop at the end of the sentence: `XX 0.0. vs. 2.895.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<![,\.])\b(\d+[,.]\d+)\b(?![.,]\d)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pVmdbV/1)

The negative lookahead matches `.` or `,` followed by another digit. So this won't match a date like `15.10.2044` but it will match `2.895.` because the `.` isn't followed by another digit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how one may go about forming a regular expression that matches what it should match and doesn't match what it shouldn't.

We are given five examples:

1. | Capture| 1.304 /XXX 0.0000 XX 15/Oct/2000 | (match 1.304 and 0.000)
2. | Capture | XXX 1.304% - XXX 15.10.2044 XXX |   (match 1.304)
3. | Capture| XXX 11,8275% XXX1 AAA    |           (match 11,8275)
4. | Capture| XX 0.0. vs. 2.895    |               (match 2.895)
5. | Capture| XX 0.0. vs. 2.895.    |              (match 2.895)

It may be helpful to write down the rules that are implied by the above examples. Once these rules are identified the construction of the needed regular expression is relatively straightforward.

- 1-5 suggest that every string to be matched represents either a positive float, a positive integer containing a comma or zero (I will refer to the first two collectively as "positive numbers");
- 1-5 suggest that all matched strings are to be preceded by a space;
- 1-5 suggest that all strings that represent a positive number are followed by a percent sign, a space or a period followed by a space;
- 1,4,5 suggest that all strings that represent zero are followed by a space; and
- 3 suggests that the string may contain a comma, presumably preceded by a string that represents a positive integer and followed by a string that represents a non-negative integer, but that the string may not contain both a comma and a period.

Strings that represent positive numbers are substantially different than than those that represent zeroes, so we need an alternation that looks like this:

```
(?<= )(?:<positive number>|<zero>)
```

As both types of strings to be matched are to be preceded by a space the *positive lookbehind* `(?<= )` can precede the non-capture group. For matching strings representing positive numbers we have:

```
[1-9]\d*[.,]\d+(?=%| |\. )
```

where `(?=%| |\. )` is a *positive lookahead*.

On the other hand, the part of the regex that matches strings that represent zero is simply

```
0.0+(?= )
```

The regular expression is therefore:

```
(?<= )(?:[1-9]\d*[.,]\d+(?=%| |\. )|\.(?!\d)|0.0+(?= ))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JkieD6/1)